# I am looking for a word that is synonymous with "syntactic expletive" to describe the purpose of the word "there"

Tags: grammar, terminology, parts-of-speech

It is a word that describes the purpose of the word "there" in a sentence such as,
"There is a bird in the tree." Expletive is one word, but there is another, longer word, and I need that word.

Comment: The purpose of "there" in this construction is to postpone the appearance of the true subject "bird," essentially for sentence variety. Interjection might be the word you're seeking.

Comment: Wait, are you sure you mean "expletive"?  Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: [This ELL question might help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34099/what-exactly-is-the-word-there-in-an-existential-construction-and-related-que) - is the word you're looking for "existential"?

Comment: @aparente001 Never use a dictionary for grammar questions! *Expletive* is a regular linguistics term used to refer to dummy elements.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I reopened the question... only to close it as a duplicate. Hope that works. (Interestingly, nobody mentioned "expletives" there.)

Comment: @Laurel , aparente001 [See here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22expletive+there%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari#ip=1) for examples. I think the new link’s probably ok, but it asks about the name of the clause/construction, not the dummy subject. I think it will come out in the wash, though.

Comment: Your choices are: *dummy subject / dummy pronoun / existential ‘there’ / existential subject / expletive ‘there’ / anticipatory subject / anticipatory ‘there’ / inserted ‘there’.* I’d avoid the ‘anticipatory’ ones.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - what a funny term.  Thanks.  When I saw *expletive*, I thought of the old #(&*^(), like the supposed reason for all the gaps in the Nixon Watergate tapes.